# Software to manage a library of searchable PDF documents

Tags: linux, pdf, search, software-rec, document-management

What Linux software would you recommend for managing a library of searchable PDF documents?

I have a [Fujitsu S500](http://www.fujitsu.com/us/services/computing/peripherals/scanners/discontinued/s500.html) document scanner, and have been using the Windows software that came with it to scan and organize various documents (letters, bank statements etc). That software is of very poor quality. Besides, the drivers are proving very tricky to get working on 64-bit Windows 7.

Since I dual boot into Ubuntu, and the scanner works there out of the box, I am thinking of migrating my PDF workflow to Linux, hence my question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Recoll](http://www.recoll.org/) (Ubuntu: [recoll](http://packages.ubuntu.com/recoll) [image: Install recoll]) is a PDF (and other document) indexing tool. I'm not sure if that's what you're after: it's about searching, not about organizing — but if you have searching the filesystem may be enough organization. I don't know if it integrates with OCR software.